# Drawing parallel lines on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw parallel lines on a canvas. With one of the lines being fixed. The user inputs the distance between two lines and hence the second line is positioned accordingly. I am new to JavaScript. Please help how should I change the position of second line with user input.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
console.log('myCanvas');

//Fixed Line
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,200);
ctx.lineTo(300,200);
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.stroke();

//moving line
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,250);
ctx.lineTo(300,250);
ctx.strokeStyle='white';
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: Where have you stuck? What is the hard part? Please show some attempt, at least how you're getting the distance to the script ...

Comment: D=parseFloat(document.getElementById("ns").value);     -------D is the distance...I don't know how to use it.

Comment: As you now know the distance, disperse it to x and y components related to the both ends of the known line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

While this answer will work for some people, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63538916/13608595) answer works better for more situations (notably, it supports diagonals) and has a more thorough explanation of what is going on.

---

**Old Answer:**

You can use the `oninput` event to run every time the input is typed in. Here is an example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var input = document.getElementById("distance");
input.oninput = ()=>{
  // clear
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // draw fixed line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(50,0);
  ctx.lineTo(50,200);
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.stroke();
  let value = parseFloat(input.value);
  // draw moved line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(50+value,0);
  ctx.lineTo(50+value,250);
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<input id="distance" placeholder="Enter Distance Here (in px)" type="number">
```

Answer (score 6):

### Parallel line

To draw a line parallel to an existing line.

- Get the vector from start to end of the line.
- Use that vector to get the length of the line
- Divide the offset distance by the length of the line to get offset scale
- Scale the line vector by the offset scale
- Add the scaled vector to the ends of the line and draw.

See example function `drawLine`

### Get input

To get a value from an input element use the elements [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value) property.

To get the value when it changes, add an event listener using the elements [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function. . Do not assign a listener directly to the elements event property eg Avoid doing `myElement.oninput = ()=> {/* ... code */};`

There are a variety of input events. You can use one or more according to your needs. In this case there are two events [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event%5C) and [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). See example.

- [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event%5C) fires when the user commits a change to the value
- [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) fires when there is any change to the input value

Always assign an input value a meaningfully value, do not leave it empty if empty has no meaning.

### Example

```js
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
const myLine = {
    from: {x: 50, y: 50},
    to: {x: 150, y: 200},
    style: {strokeStyle: "#000", lineWidth: 2}
};
distanceElement.addEventListener("input", inputEvent);
var lineOffset = distanceElement.value;
drawLines();
function inputEvent(e) {
    lineOffset = e.target.value;
    drawLines();
}
function drawLines() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    drawLine(myLine);
    lineOffset !== 0 && drawLine(myLine, lineOffset);
}
function drawLine(line, offset = 0) {
    var [ox, oy] = [0, 0];  
    Object.assign(ctx, line.style);
    if (offset) {
        const [dx, dy] = [line.from.x - line.to.x, line.from.y - line.to.y];
        const scale = offset / (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5;
        [ox, oy] = [-dy * scale, dx * scale];
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(ox + line.from.x, oy + line.from.y);
    ctx.lineTo(ox + line.to.x, oy + line.to.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
input {display:block;}
```

```html
<label for="distanceElement">Line offset distance:</label>
<input id="distanceElement" placeholder="Enter Distance" type="number" value="0">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```